# Can someone please tell me why this code doesnt print anything?

Tags: c++

I have to write a code that compares three text files and i cant for the life of me find out why this wont print anything:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream mousefile;
    mousefile.open(argv[1]);
    string mouse_dna;
    getline(mousefile, mouse_dna);

    ifstream humanfile;
    humanfile.open(argv[2]);
    string human_dna;
    getline(humanfile, human_dna);

    ifstream unknownfile;
    unknownfile.open(argv[3]);
    string unknown_dna;
    getline(unknownfile, unknown_dna);

    int len = mouse_dna.size();
    int mouseDistance = 0, humanDistance = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        if(mouse_dna[i] != unknown_dna[i])
            mouseDistance++;
            return mouseDistance;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        if(human_dna[i] != unknown_dna[i])
            humanDistance++;
            return humanDistance;


    double similarity_scoreH = (len - humanDistance) / len; 
    double similarity_scoreM = (len - mouseDistance) / len; 
    cout << "MouseCompare = " << similarity_scoreM << endl;
    cout << "HumanCompare = " << similarity_scoreH << endl;

    if (similarity_scoreH == similarity_scoreM)
        cout << "identity cannot be determined" << endl;
    else if (similarity_scoreH > similarity_scoreM)
        cout << "human" << endl;
    else if (similarity_scoreM > similarity_scoreH)
        cout << "mouse" << endl;


}
```

It compiles properly, and doesn't give any errors, but when i rut it as:

```
./DNA mouseDNA.txt humanDNA.txt unknownDNA.txt
```

it still does nothing.
I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! This is not a Python. It will exit on 'return mouseDistance;'

Comment: Diehard Python fan ?

Comment: Python-style blocks or not, the returns are a problem.

Comment: Yeah i was taught on python and just recently switched to c++, so if i remove the returns, it prints, but its not correct, do i need something to return the value of mouseDistance?

Comment: If you want to have more than one statement in the "then" portion of your if/then construct, you need to put curly braces around them.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't print anything because it's returning before the instructions to print (`return mouseDistance;` or `return humanDistance;`). Make your function more verbose by printing progress messsages before each return statement.

Answer (score 0):

As already has pointed out, you return too early. I modify your code:

1. I put brackets around the if block and for block.
2. I have a return statement at the end.

This is a start. You may have to add more checking, for example, if the file is open correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream mousefile;
    mousefile.open(argv[1]);
    string mouse_dna;
    getline(mousefile, mouse_dna);

    ifstream humanfile;
    humanfile.open(argv[2]);
    string human_dna;
    getline(humanfile, human_dna);

    ifstream unknownfile;
    unknownfile.open(argv[3]);
    string unknown_dna;
    getline(unknownfile, unknown_dna);

    int len = mouse_dna.size();
    int mouseDistance = 0, humanDistance = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(mouse_dna[i] != unknown_dna[i])
        {
            mouseDistance++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(human_dna[i] != unknown_dna[i])
        {
            humanDistance++;
        }
    }


    double similarity_scoreH = (len - humanDistance) / len; 
    double similarity_scoreM = (len - mouseDistance) / len; 
    cout << "MouseCompare = " << similarity_scoreM << endl;
    cout << "HumanCompare = " << similarity_scoreH << endl;

    if (similarity_scoreH == similarity_scoreM)
        cout << "identity cannot be determined" << endl;
    else if (similarity_scoreH > similarity_scoreM)
        cout << "human" << endl;
    else if (similarity_scoreM > similarity_scoreH)
        cout << "mouse" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use arg[1], arg[2], and arg[3]. You may want arg[0], arg[1], and arg[2].